# Tier price not working on Migration_Default attribute set Magento 2

Tags: magento, migration

I just migrated to magento 2.2.6. If I change the attribute set of product from 'Migration_Default' to 'Default', then it works fine. Also that it is just not showing on product detail page, but working fine in cart page on both attribute sets.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved. In my case it was a qty attribute that was duplicated, i.e their were 2 qty attributes in 'Migration_Default' attribute set. So I just made the values of all products with 'Migration_Default' attribute set, to zero '0' from admin. (catalog > product > filter > {attribute_Set -> Migration_Default, status -> enabled} > select all > update attributes > quantity attribute -> 0  > save). Hurry!